# Wait set state finishes to call another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, promise, state

I have an useEffect where i made an api request to get data and feed an array named **'opcoes'** that is declarated as a React useState. So it is something like const [opcoes, setOpcoes] = useState([]). After that i get the api response it should **setOpcoes** with the value that i got and then call a function named **'comparaQtd()'**. The problem is that this function is being called before the set state finishes and i need it to be filled to compare it with another array in the function comparaQtd(). Does anyone know how can i wait this? I have already tryed to put the set state in a **promise** and the otherFunction in the resolve of the promise, but it still not working...

```
//how it was before
setOpcoes(opcoesResponse.data); 
comparaQtd();


//how it is now with promise
const execState = () => new Promise(resolve => {
   setOpcoes(opcoesResponse.data);
   resolve();
});

execState().then(() => {
   comparaQtd();
});
```

Comment: Trying to *wait* is the wrong approach.  You could make use of `useEffect` to respond to state changes, or perhaps pass the data directly to the `compareQtd` function.